# Asp.net core docker - skip ctrl-c message

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have a default asp.net core dockerfile (as created by VS Tools for Docker):

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

When i run my image using `docker run myimage` i get this message in an interactive console:

`Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: /app
Now listening on: http://[::]:80
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.`

If i then press `Ctrl+C` and type `docker start <imgid>`, then i no longer see this message, and my bash console is not blocked.

How can i do `docker run` bypassing this annoying message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-d` flag with docker run so that the image starts in detached mode. In this case you will not see any output but docker will be running in background.

```
docker run -d
```